# Ruby doesn't run on reboot

Tags: server, apache2, ruby

I have an Ubuntu 18.04 server, running Apache2, PHP, and Ruby 2.5.1.

Everything works until I reboot, and then Ruby fails to run. `ruby -v` hangs as well as any other command, there is no error as Ruby just doesn't respond.  If I purge Ruby, and reinstall it, everything works again until a reboot.

I tried RVM, from source, and rbenv, they will install and work until the server reboots.

```
$ which ruby 
/usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/bin/ruby 

$ locate ruby
can not stat () `/var/lib/mlocate/mlocate.db': No such file or directory
```

What could be the cause of the issue?

Comment: Post the output of following commands: `which ruby`    and   `locate ruby`

Comment: which ruby

/usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/bin/ruby

locate:

locate: can not stat () `/var/lib/mlocate/mlocate.db': No such file or directory

Comment: @abu_bua So update on this, if I kill all the processes stop anything that spawns a new ruby process, like apache2, then repair rvm, then restart the services I can get ruby working again without reinstalling it.

But it breaks on reboot again.